# Difference between x = document.getElementById("id").className = & x = document.getElementById("id"), x.className =

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects, dom-events

What's the difference in the codes below:

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-click">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="clickDrp()">Hover Over me</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-animate-zoom w3-bar-block" id="cont">        
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink1</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink2</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink3</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink4</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickDrp(){
        var x = document.getElementById("cont").className;
        if(x.search("w3-show") == -1)
            x += " w3-show";
        else
            x = x.replace(" w3-show","");
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-click">
    <button class="w3-btn" onclick="clickDrp()">Hover Over me</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-animate-zoom w3-bar-block" id="cont">        
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink1</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink2</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink3</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SomeLink4</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickDrp(){
        var x = document.getElementById("cont");
        if(x.className.search("w3-show") == -1)
            x.className += " w3-show";
        else
            x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show","");
    }
</script>
```

In the second one Dropdown menu works fine.
In the first it does not even if x is made global variable.

I'm new to Javascript and I'm unable to figure out the reason.
Can someone reason it out?

PS: I've used w3-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first variant, your variable `x` is a copy of the `className` string. Any change you do to `x` will be to that variable, not to the original `className` property value.

In the second variant, your variable `x` is a copy of the object reference that `getElementById` returns. As long as you don't assign a new value to `x`, it will point to the DOM object. Any *mutation* done to `x` (i.e. by assigning to one of its properties, like `className`) will affect the DOM object, and so the effect will be visible on the web document.

Comment: what if x was a global variable ??

Comment: @PrajvalM makes no difference.

Comment: @PrajvalM, that is irrelevant. When you assign a string value to a variable (local,  global or a property of some object -- it does not matter), you are assigning a copy. Strings are primitive values (immutable). The only way to change the value of the `className` property, is to assign a new string to it. You cannot do this by an assignment to a variable, it needs to be to the `className` property.

Comment: is there a way such that i can reference x to document.getElementById("cont").className in a single step as in part 1 of the code.

Comment: No, that is not possible. As I explained, when you assign a string, you don't assign a reference (and that is not possible either), but the actual, primitive value. Assigning something else to `x` is never going to influence what was assigned to `x` *before* that last assignment. This is true for *all* assignments, irrespective of data type. The way to overcome this, is exactly what variant 2 is doing: using an object reference and assigning to object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not stated correctly. The difference is between

```
x = document.getElementById(“id”).className;
x = ...;
```

and

```
x = document.getElementById(“id”);
x.className = ...;
```

Here is a simpler example of the your problem:

```
// Case 1
var a = { foo: "bar" };
var b = a.foo;
b += "baz";
console.log(a.foo); // "bar"
console.log(b); // "barbaz"

// Case 2
var a = { foo: "bar" };
var b = a.foo;
a.foo += "baz";
console.log(a.foo); // "barbaz"
console.log(b); // "bar"
```

The assignment `a.foo += "baz";` is semantically the same as `a.foo = a.foo + "baz";`, or, in your case:

```
x.className = x.className + " w3-show";
```

By using the [+= operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) you created a new string and then assigned that string to `x.className`. This stems from the fact that property "className" on x is a key in the object's property map to the string value "bar" ([more on object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)).

Answer (score 0):

This was foolish of me to ask such a question. The thing is x here returns a string which is a seperate copy, instead if i only return x as document.getElementById('id') will retuen an object which is passing by reference and thus x can be modified.